# How do I mount SD Card on BQ Aquaris M10 FHD Frieza?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sd-card, aquaris, m10

How do I mount SD Card on BQ Aquaris M10 FHD Frieza
I just received my new BQ m10 tablet and when I first inserted the microSD card, it was recognized and I was able to copy some files out to it via File Manager. After a restart, I no longer see the drive in File Manager. I do see it in External Drives, but when I try to format or unmount it, I get an error: "The device could not be unmounted because it is busy."

I tried re-formatting the card on my laptop as both FAT and ExFat and when I re-insert it into the m10 tablet, it still will not mount in "File Manager," but is recognized by SD Card Managment/External Drives.

Answer (score 0):

In the file manager application, have you tried to unlock the acces to the SD card ? (on the upper right corner of the screen you can see three lines for more options, including unlocking acces to the sd card)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I only see three options in file manager options:  properties, settings, and go to. I should add that I am running 15.04 (OTA 10-1).

Comment: Same for me: I do not have this option.

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet, you need to tap the SD Card icon in File Manager first before you get the unlock option.